# React: Assigning array to variable using useState to pass into modal

Tags: arrays, reactjs, modal-dialog, prop

I made a JSON file for the upcoming NFL season.  In this component I have a working fetch method that gets my data, and I've named the variable "squads".  Now I want to press a button to filter out the selected team's schedule and display it in a modal.  I've hard coded my button in this example.  My modal component works fine, and I have {props.children} in the modal's body to accept my data.

In the code below you'll see that I'm trying to assign the filtered team to the selectedTeam variable using useState.  The error message I'm getting just says my variables are undefined.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Modal from "./Components/Modal";

export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [squads, setSquads] = useState([]);
  const [modalTitleBackground, setModalTitleBackground] = useState("");
  const [image, setImage] = useState("");
  const [selectedTeam, setSelectedTeam] = useState([]);

  const url = "../nfl2021.json";

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();
      setSquads(data.teams);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  // const filterTeam = (team) => {
  //   const theTeam = squads.filter((squad) => squad.name === team);
  //   setModalTitleBackground(theTeam[0].topBG);
  //   // setTitle(theTeam[0].name);
  //   setNickname(theTeam[0].nickname);
  //   setImage(`./images/${theTeam[0].img}`);
  //   setShow(true);
  // };

  const filterTeam = (team) => {
    setSelectedTeam(squads.filter((squad) => squad.name === team));
    console.log(selectedTeam);
    setTitle(selectedTeam[0].name);
    setModalTitleBackground(selectedTeam[0].topBG);
    setImage(`./images/${selectedTeam[0].img}`);
    setShow(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => filterTeam("New England Patriots")}>
        Show Modal
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => filterTeam("Green Bay Packers")}>
        Show Modal 2
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => filterTeam("Cincinnati Bengals")}>
        Show Modal 3
      </button>
      <Modal
        image={image}
        title={title}
        backgroundColor={modalTitleBackground}
        onClose={() => setShow(false)}
        show={show}
      >
        <p>
          This is the modal body using props.children in the modal component.
        </p>
        <p>The {title} 2021 schedule.</p>

        {selectedTeam[0].schedule.map((schedule, index) => {
          return (
            <p>
              Week {index + 1}: The {selectedTeam[0].nickname} play the{" "}
              {selectedTeam[0].schedule[index].opponent}.
            </p>
          );
        })}
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- In react, the state is set asynchronously. `selectedTeam` is not set until next render.

2- You can use `find` instead of `filter` and get rid of array access.

```
const [selectedTeam, setSelectedTeam] = useState({schedule: []});
```

...

```
const filterTeam = (team) => {
    let temp = squads.find((squad) => squad.name === team);
    setSelectedTeam(temp);
    console.log(temp);
    setTitle(temp.name);
    setModalTitleBackground(temp.topBG);
    setImage(`./images/${temp.img}`);
    setShow(true);
};
```

...

```
    {selectedTeam.schedule.map((match, index) => {
      return (
        <p>
          Week {index + 1}: The {selectedTeam.nickname} play the {match.opponent}.
        </p>
      );
    })}
```

Comment: palindrom, I changed the filterTeam function to reflect your answer, and that solved part of the problem. If I comment out my map method in the return, I can console.log the correct values when I click a button.  So I then changed my map function to map over ```selectedTeam``` and I get selectedTeam.map is not a function.

Comment: @JohnG.I missed that part, sorry. This edit should fix it.

Comment: palindrom, that worked! Thanks so much for taking the time to help me.  This is my first React app, and I knew there had to be an answer.  Looks like I was close, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: that worked! Thanks so much for taking the time to help me. This is my first React app, and I knew there had to be an answer. Looks like I was close, but I couldn't figure it out

Comment: Trying to do this.  Doesn't work.  How can I get the opponent's topBG to return?
```
{selectedTeam.schedule.map((match, index) => {
          return (
            <p>
              Week {index + 1}: The {selectedTeam.nickname} play the{" "}
              {match.opponent}, whose background color is{" "}
              {getBackground(match.opponent)}
            </p>
          );
        })}
```

Comment: Function for above comment is:
```
// these variables dont' work
  // const [oppColor, setOppColor] = useState("");
  // const [selectedOpp, setSelectedOpp] = useState([]);

  const getBackground = (opp) => {
    let temporary = squads.find((squad) => squad.name === opp);
    console.log(temporary); // returns opponents array, which is good
    // below returns cannot read property 'topBG' of undefined
    // console.log(temporary.topBG);
    // setSelectedOpp(temporary);
    // setOppColor(temporary.topBG);
    // return oppColor;
    return;
```

Comment: If it's improper for me to ask you these questions directly, let me know.  I'm knew to all of this.

Comment: You must not call hooks inside `return`: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#rules-of-hooks . You dont need to call them to get opponent's topBg anyway. Just return the value in `getBackground`. What's the output of `console.log(temporary)`? If it contains topBG, this should work `return temporary.topBG`; (By the way, `temporary` is an object, not an array)

Comment: Thanks again for answering, but it's not working.  Yes, ```console.log(temporary)``` spits out my object.  Yes, topBG is part of the object.  If I ```console.log(temporary.topBG)```, the hex codes do show up in the console.  But ```return temporary.topBG``` just gets me "TypeError: Cannot read property 'topBG' of undefined".  So it boggles my mind why my hex codes show up in the console, but then I get the undefined error at the same time.

Comment: `getBackground`is called inside a loop. So, the iteration `console.log`prints `temporary`successfully is different than the iteration you got the error. Do the following: `console.log(opp + " " + JSON.stringify(temporary)); return temporary === undefined ? "" : temporary.topBG;`

Comment: It will let you see the opponents for which`squads.find`returns undefined.

Comment: It works!  Thanks again. I'll have to do some more studying to figure out exactly what your code is doing.  I'll leave you alone now.  I don't want to abuse your generosity.